# Implementing jquery-ui in scala.js

Tags: jquery, scala, jquery-ui, scala.js

I am trying to make calls to the jquery-ui from scala.js. I have tried modifying the way the jquery library is implemented but without success so far. So I have defined the following trait and package object:

```
trait JQueryUI extends js.Object {

    def apply(selector: String): JQueryUI = ???
    val buttonset: js.Any = ???
}

package object jqueryui extends js.GlobalScope {
    val jQueryUI: JQueryUI = ???
}
```

And then added a JSApp as follows:

```
object JQueryUIApp extends JSApp {
    def main(): Unit = {
        jqueryui.jQueryUI("#sports").buttonset
    }   
}
```

But on my JavaScript console I get the following error:

> TypeError: ScalaJS.g["jQueryUI"] is not a function    (0,
>   ScalaJS.g["jQueryUI"])("#sports")["buttonset"]

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring the `val jQueryUI` like that in your package object, you tell the Scala.js that this corresponds to a global variable in JavaScript named `jQueryUI`. Now that's not true: the actual variable you're looking for is named `jQuery`. You can fix this by naming explicitly the value with `@JSName`:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSName

package object jqueryui extends js.GlobalScope {
  @JSName("jQuery")
  val jQueryUI: JQueryUI = ???
}
```

However, since jQuery-UI is literally an *extension* of the `jQuery` object, I would define this with extension methods on the `JQuery` trait of `scalajs-jquery`. This will allow to use the normal `jQuery` for both usages (jQuery-core methods *and* jQuery-UI methods). The general mechanism is explained in [the Calling JavaScript guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html) under the title "Monkey patching". In your case, it would look like this:

```
trait JQueryUI extends JQuery {
  val buttonset: js.Any = ???
}

object JQueryUI {
  implicit def jQueryUIExtensions(query: JQuery): JQueryUI =
    query.asInstanceOf[JQueryUI]
}
```

Using these definitions, you can do:

```
import org.scalajs.jquery._
import JQueryUI.jQueryUIExtensions

def main(): Unit = {
  jQuery("#sports").buttonset
}
```

Note that I'm using the normal `jquery.jQuery` object, which returns a normal `JQuery` object, but then I call the `buttonset` value, which is defined in `JQueryUI`. This works because of the implicit conversion `jQueryUIExtensions`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just had to change "val buttonset" to a "def buttonset()"

Comment: Is it possible to add function to a trait JQueryStatic. For example, to get result like this jQuery.someFunction() ?

Comment: @AlexKarasev Yes. Use exactly the same technique, but replace `JQuery` by `JQueryStatic` in the `implicit def`. The technique works for any JavaScript type.